# How can I limit the result in a category using moongose

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb, the collection has a field displayInCategories. The collection contains 1000's of data wrt to different displayInCategories. 
Is it possible to limit the records to <=5 for all the available displayInCategories. 
I didn't want to limit the record on whole result, I need to limit the record as per the displayInCategories

Comment: explain by posting your collection here...

Comment: $limit Limits the number of documents passed to the next stage in the pipeline, using aggregation-framework, see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit

Answer (score 0):

This might get you going:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$displayInCategories", // group by displayInCategories
        "docs": { $push: "$$ROOT" } // remember all documents for this category
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "docs": { $slice: [ "$docs", 5 ] } // limit the items in each "docs" array to 5
    }
}])
```

You might want to apply a `$sort` stage at the start to make sure you don't get random documents but rather the "top 5" based on some criteria.